# generate column with capped values in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, max, min

I have a data.table similar to the following one:

```
| ID | C1 | C2 | C3  |
|  1 |  1 | 20 | 400 |
|  2 |  0 | 15 | 500 |
|  3 |  0 |  2 | 350 |
|  4 |  1 |  4 | 402 |
|  5 |  1 |  8 | 333 |
```

And I want to generate a new column "CALC" applying a function like this one:

```
func <- function(a, b, c){
      pol <- a*b-0.01*c
      value <- min(max(pol, 0), 5)
      }
```

What I thought it was going to give was me the pol solution in each row, capped by 0 and 5. So, instead of

```
| ID | C1 | C2 | C3  | CALC  |
|  1 |  1 | 20 | 400 | 16    |
|  2 |  0 | 15 | 500 | -5    |
|  3 |  0 |  2 | 350 | -3.5  |
|  4 |  1 |  4 | 402 | -0.02 |
|  5 |  1 |  8 | 333 | 4.67  |
```

it should return

```
| ID | C1 | C2 | C3  | CALC  |
|  1 |  1 | 20 | 400 |  5    |
|  2 |  0 | 15 | 500 |  0    |
|  3 |  0 |  2 | 350 |  0    |
|  4 |  1 |  4 | 402 |  0    |
|  5 |  1 |  8 | 333 | 4.67  |
```

But instead, what it gives is the following dt:

```
| ID | C1 | C2 | C3  | CALC  |
|  1 |  1 | 20 | 400 |  5    |
|  2 |  0 | 15 | 500 |  5    |
|  3 |  0 |  2 | 350 |  5    |
|  4 |  1 |  4 | 402 |  5    |
|  5 |  1 |  8 | 333 |  5    |
```

So, if I'm not wrong, it's getting the max of the values in the column (capping it by 5) and putting in along the column. Not what I intented, which would be getting the max of each row alone.

Is there any "easy" way to fix it? The original dt is more complex, so it wouldn't be possible to simply do `dt[, CALC := func(C1, C2, C3), by="ID"]`, as it should be something like `by=.(GROUP1, GROUP2, ID)`, and I'm pretty sure it has to be simpler. Maybe there's an easy way through the function itself?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: maybe `by=seq_len(dt[,.N])`?

Comment: It works for the reduced model I'm working with, but I can see how it takes it a lot of time for such a few rows (100, vs the real one of something like 10 million). Is there any other possibility?

Comment: check out Onyambu's vectorized `func`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `pmin` and `pmax`

```
func <- function(a, b, c){
  pol <- a*b-0.01*c
  pmin(pmax(pol, 0), 5)
}


transform(dat,s=func(C1,C2,C3))
  ID C1 C2  C3    s
1  1  1 20 400 5.00
2  2  0 15 500 0.00
3  3  0  2 350 0.00
4  4  1  4 402 0.00
5  5  1  8 333 4.67

 setDT(dat)[,CALC:=func(C1,C2,C3)]
 dat
   ID C1 C2  C3 CALC
1:  1  1 20 400 5.00
2:  2  0 15 500 0.00
3:  3  0  2 350 0.00
4:  4  1  4 402 0.00
5:  5  1  8 333 4.67
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's the answer I was looking for.